# Rhandsontable collect values from logical == TRUE

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I'm trying to collect the value of a column ('Type') in a rhandsontable based on the the selection of the adjacent logical column ('Tick'). I want to create a vector of all the Type's based on the which rows are ticked.

I will use the vector to subset the columns in the other rhandsontable 'Aims'

I'm getting the error

> Warning: Error in match: 'match' requires vector arguments

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

orgs <- c("Community leaders/representatives",
          "Members of local community/indigenous committees",
          "Landowners/customary area owners",
          "National government",
          "Sub-national or local government",
          "Managed area manager/personnel",
          "International NGO",
          "Local or national NGO",
          "Community based organizations - women’s groups",
          "Community based organizations - men’s groups",
          "Community based organizations - youth/school groups",
          "Community based organizations - religious groups",
          "Community based organizations - conservation groups",
          "Industry", 
          "Private sector",
          "Academic institute or research facility",
          "Other")

proj_aim3 <- data.frame(Category = c("Area", "Condition", "Diversity"))
proj_aim3 <- cbind(proj_aim3, setNames( lapply(orgs, function(x) x=NA), orgs) )

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('Intiated'),
  verbatimTextOutput('selected'),
  br(),
  rHandsontableOutput("Aims2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  cats <- c("Community leaders/representatives", "Members of local community/indigenous committees", "Landowners/customary area owners", "National government", "Sub-national or local government", "Managed area manager/personnel",
            "International NGO", "Local or national NGO", "Community based organizations - women’s groups", "Community based organizations - men’s groups",
            "Community based organizations - youth/school groups", "Community based organizations - religious groups",  "Industry", "Private sector", 
            "Academic institute or research facility", "Not recorded", "Other")
  
  DF <- data.frame(Tick = rep(FALSE, length(cats)), Type = cats, Name = rep("", length(cats)))
  
  output$Intiated <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(DF, selectCallback = TRUE, readOnly = FALSE)
  )
  
  selected2 <- reactive({     
    dat <- hot_to_r(input$Intiated)     
    if (any(dat[[1]])) {       
      dat[which(dat[[1]]), 2]      
    }   
  })
  
  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    cat(paste(selected2(), collapse = "\n"))
  })
  
  
  Aims_DF_NEW <- proj_aim3
  imps2 <- c("Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary")
  
  sel <- selected2
  
  output$Aims2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    
    Aims_DF_NEW <- Aims_DF_NEW[, which(names(Aims_DF_NEW) %in% sel)]

    rhandsontable(Aims_DF_NEW, rowHeaders = NULL, width = 1500, height = 600) %>%
      hot_col(col = "Category", readOnly = T) %>%
      hot_cols(cols = Aims_DF_NEW[,2:ncol(Aims_DF_NEW)], type = "autocomplete", source = imps2, strict = TRUE, colWidths = 200)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following approach. Use `hot_to_r` to get your data from the handsontable as an R object. Check the first column for any checked items (which would be `TRUE` boolean values). If there are, you can extract the second column of data, using the row indices based on the first column that are `TRUE`.

Note that the code in `output$selected` can be moved to a separate `reactive` expression, so that the selected results can be used elsewhere.

Also, you would need parentheses for `selected2()`. `selected2()` should return a character vector of the `Type` selected.

To select the appropriate columns from your second data.frame `Aims_DF_NEW`, you can try:

```
Aims_DF_NEW[, names(Aims_DF_NEW) %in% selected2(), drop = F]
```

This will only include columns in `Aims_DF_NEW` that are included in the `selected2()` result. `drop = F` is added so the result is not coerced to a vector if only 1 column selected (and remains a data.frame).

Here is a revised version to subset the second table based on the first table (second table simplified to demonstrate).

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

orgs <- c("Community leaders/representatives",
          "Members of local community/indigenous committees",
          "Landowners/customary area owners",
          "National government",
          "Sub-national or local government",
          "Managed area manager/personnel",
          "International NGO",
          "Local or national NGO",
          "Community based organizations - women’s groups",
          "Community based organizations - men’s groups",
          "Community based organizations - youth/school groups",
          "Community based organizations - religious groups",
          "Community based organizations - conservation groups",
          "Industry", 
          "Private sector",
          "Academic institute or research facility",
          "Other")

proj_aim3 <- data.frame(Category = c("Area", "Condition", "Diversity"))
proj_aim3 <- cbind(proj_aim3, setNames( lapply(orgs, function(x) x=NA), orgs))
Aims_DF_NEW <- proj_aim3
imps2 <- c("Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary")

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('Intiated'),
  verbatimTextOutput('selected'),
  br(),
  rHandsontableOutput("Aims2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  cats <- c("Community leaders/representatives", "Members of local community/indigenous committees", "Landowners/customary area owners", "National government", "Sub-national or local government", "Managed area manager/personnel",
            "International NGO", "Local or national NGO", "Community based organizations - women’s groups", "Community based organizations - men’s groups",
            "Community based organizations - youth/school groups", "Community based organizations - religious groups",  "Industry", "Private sector", 
            "Academic institute or research facility", "Not recorded", "Other")
  
  DF <- data.frame(Tick = rep(FALSE, length(cats)), Type = cats, Name = rep("", length(cats)))
  
  output$Intiated <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(DF, selectCallback = TRUE, readOnly = FALSE)
  )
  
  selected2 <- reactive({     
    dat <- hot_to_r(input$Intiated)     
    if (any(dat[[1]])) {       
      dat[which(dat[[1]]), 2]      
    }   
  })
  
  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    cat(paste(selected2(), collapse = "\n"))
  })
  
  output$Aims2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(Aims_DF_NEW[, names(Aims_DF_NEW) %in% selected2(), drop = F], rowHeaders = NULL, width = 1500, height = 600) 
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This works well although I'm struggling to access the values as a ``reactive`` expression. I have added a second term 
``selected2 <- reactive({
    dat <- hot_to_r(input$Intiated)
    if (any(dat[[1]])) {
      dat[which(dat[[1]]), 2]
     }
  })``

which is returning an error "Unsupported object type: character Can't extract column types" when i try to subset a the second rhandsontable

Comment: @ThomasWorthington Please see edited example and let me know if this helps. Make sure to access the character vector as `selected2()` with parentheses. If this doesn't work, feel free to edit the question with more detail on how you're using `selected2` with a second rhandsontable.

Comment: @'Ben' I've edited the question to clarify what I'm aiming for

Comment: `selected2` is a `reactive` expression, so to use this you need parentheses: `selected2()`. Some of the second `rhandsontable` is a bit confusing for me, but I was able to get this to work in a simplified form: `output$Aims2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(Aims_DF_NEW[, selected2(), drop = F], rowHeaders = NULL, width = 1500, height = 600) 
  })`...here you can subset your `Aims_DF_NEW` data.frame using `selected2()`...`drop = F` is added so if you select one column it doesn't get coerced to a vector (stays a data frame)...

Comment: You can also try `Aims_DF_NEW[, names(Aims_DF_NEW) %in% selected2(), drop = F]` to make sure the columns are available from `Aims_DF_NEW`

Answer (score 1):

Putting together the answers from @Ben. Here is a solution

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

orgs <- c("Community leaders/representatives",
          "Members of local community/indigenous committees",
          "Landowners/customary area owners",
          "National government",
          "Sub-national or local government",
          "Managed area manager/personnel",
          "International NGO",
          "Local or national NGO",
          "Community based organizations - women’s groups",
          "Community based organizations - men’s groups",
          "Community based organizations - youth/school groups",
          "Community based organizations - religious groups",
          "Community based organizations - conservation groups",
          "Industry", 
          "Private sector",
          "Academic institute or research facility",
          "Other")

proj_aim3 <- data.frame(Category = c("Area", "Condition", "Diversity"))
proj_aim3 <- cbind(proj_aim3, setNames( lapply(orgs, function(x) x=NA), orgs) )

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('Intiated'),
  verbatimTextOutput('selected'),
  br(),
  rHandsontableOutput("Aims2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  cats <- c("Community leaders/representatives", "Members of local community/indigenous committees", "Landowners/customary area owners", "National government", "Sub-national or local government", "Managed area manager/personnel",
            "International NGO", "Local or national NGO", "Community based organizations - women’s groups", "Community based organizations - men’s groups",
            "Community based organizations - youth/school groups", "Community based organizations - religious groups",  "Industry", "Private sector", 
            "Academic institute or research facility", "Not recorded", "Other")
  
  DF <- data.frame(Tick = rep(FALSE, length(cats)), Type = cats, Name = rep("", length(cats)))
  
  output$Intiated <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(DF, selectCallback = TRUE, readOnly = FALSE)
  )
  
  selected2 <- reactive({     
    dat <- hot_to_r(input$Intiated)     
    if (any(dat[[1]])) {       
      dat[which(dat[[1]]), 2]      
    }   
  })
  
  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    cat(paste(selected2(), collapse = "\n"))
  })
  
  
  Aims_DF_NEW <- proj_aim3
  imps2 <- c("Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary")
  
  Cat <- data.frame(Aims_DF_NEW[, 1])
  colnames(Cat) <- c("Category")

  output$Aims2 <- renderRHandsontable({   rhandsontable(cbind(Cat, Aims_DF_NEW[, selected2(), drop = F]), rowHeaders = NULL, width = 1500, height = 600) %>%
      hot_col(col = "Category", readOnly = T) %>%
      hot_cols(cols = Aims_DF_NEW[,2:ncol(Aims_DF_NEW)], type = "autocomplete", source = imps2, strict = TRUE, colWidths = 200)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```